# Optional or boolean elements to specify characteristics in XML schema?

Tags: xsd

I'm trying to create an XML schema to describe some aspects of hospitals. A hospital may have 24 hour coverage on: emergency services, operating room, pharmacist, etc. The entire list is relatively short - around 10. The coverage may be on more than one of these services.

My question is how best to represent this. I'm thinking along the lines of:

```
<coverage>
    <emergencyServices/>
    <operatingRoom/>
</coverage>
```

Basically, the services are optional and, if they exist, the coverage is offered by the hospital.

Alternatively, I could have:

```
<coverage>
    <emergencyServices>true</emergencyServices>
    <operatingRoom>true</operatingRoom>
    <pharmacist>false</pharmacist>
</coverage>
```

In this case, I require all the elements, but a value of false means that the coverage isn't offered.

There are probably other approaches.

What's the best practice for something like this? And, if I use the first option, what type should the elements be in the schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice here depends really on the consumer.

**The short and simple rule is that *markup* is for structure, and *content* is for data. So having them contain `xs:boolean` values is generally the best course.**

Now, on to the options:

1. Having separate untyped elements is simple and clear; sometimes processing systems may have difficulty reading them, because some XML-relational mappers may not see any data in the elements to put in relational tables. But if they had values, like `<emergencyServices>true</emergencyServices>`, then the relational table would have a value to hold.
2. Again, if you have fixed element names, it means if your consumer is using a system that maps the XML to a database, every time you add a service, a schema change will have to be made.

   There are several other ways; each has trade-offs:
3. Using a `<xs:string>` with an `enumeration`, and allow multiple copies. Then you could have `<coverage>emergencyServices</coverage><coverage>operatingRoom</coverage>.` It makes adding to the list simpler, but allows duplicates. This scheme does not require schema changes in the database for the consumer.
4. You could use attributes on the `<coverage>` element. They would have a `xs:boolean` type, but still require a schema change. Of course, this evokes the [attribute vs. element](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-eleatt.html) argument.

One good resource is [Chapter 11](http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/effectivexml/chapters/11.html) of [Effective XML](http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/effectivexml/). At least this should be read before making a final decision.