# Optional element or boolean attribute

Tags: xml, solr

I'm in the process of defining an XML schema that will contain search query information that will be (re)imported into Solr for processing. One of the aspects that I want to save for the results of the query is whether or not they were visited and if so how long. Now I'm wondering how best to define this data in my structure, I can either use an attribute for the 'result' element or I can add an optional child element to hold all the information on a click.

With an attribute:

```
<result index="1" clicked="true">
    <timeViewed>45.21</timeViewed>
    <title>Alpha</title>
</result>
<result index="2" clicked="false">
    <title>Beta</title>
</result>
```

With a child element:

```
<result index="1">
    <clickInfo timeViewed="45.21"/>
    <title>Alpha</title>
</result>
<result index="2">
    <title>Beta</title>
</result>
```

Finally, in accordance with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260254/optional-or-boolean-elements-to-specify-characteristics-in-xml-schema):

```
<result index="1">
    <clicked timeViewed="45.21">true</clicked>
    <title>Alpha</title>
</result>
<result index="2">
    <clicked>false</clicked>
    <title>Beta</title>
</result>
```

As I'll be indexing large volumes of these XML files into Solr and possibly MongoDB I'm wondering what the most efficient structure would be. Will these differences even have a noticeable effect on the transform process prior to loading the information into the database or index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally go for the attribute, reasons are

- It makes always clear whether or not the element was clicket or not (logic like "if i do not specify, then assume A" is something I have never liked)
- The xml always has the same structure, wheter the element was visited or not, this may not look like a big deal, but makes the parsing easier and less prone to errors
- You may save space as it is cheaper to add an attribute rather than a new tag, but that might not be always the case, as it will depend on how often the elements are clicked.

Comment: Convincing arguments. I agree that it's probable better not to rely on optional elements for boolean values as it will increase parsing complexity and makes things less structured and transparent.